# TeXStudio: output-directory=build except for PdF? (Linux Mint)

Tags: texstudio

I've figured out that if I put `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build %.tex` into the PdfLaTeX Command Line, it puts almost all the files into a folder (Sidenote: is there a way to have TeXStudio make that folder? So far I've only seen this work if the folder is already there), and this in the BibTeX line: `bibtex build/% -include-directory=build`.

There is still a `.bbl` and a `.blg` file, can those somehow be generated in the `build` folder too?

I also just realized that TeXStudio is no longer finding all the auxiliary files it just created, even though I also added `./build/` to the Log Files Search Path. How do I deal with this?

The original issue was to keep the PDF file in the main directory. How do I achieve this? I've tried using `-aux-directory` but that gives me an `unknown option` error, so that might not be possible for me.

Ideally, I'd like to just have the `.tex` file and the PDF in the main directory, and everything else in the `build` folder. Is this possible? I'm on Linux Mint.

Comment: I never use this options. Life is much easier if you don't use a build folder but leave the files where all the tools are looking for them.

Comment: I've come to that conclusion too. Now I'm just looking for a way to hide all files that aren't `.tex` or PDF, because I keep having to look for these in the pile of auxiliary files. Not that big of a deal though.

Comment: If you just want to keep the pdf in the main directory, have a look at ltx2any. This avoids all the many drawbacks of setting an output folder by actually doing the compilation in a separate folder.

Comment: Discussions in texstudio repo under the almost identical title and description: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/discussions/2824